# Outputting post title without encoding

Tags: encoding

I'm setting up a way to feed the title of a WP post as the title argument for a [reddit button](http://www.reddit.com/buttons/). It works fine unless there is an encoded character in the string:

```
apostrophe&#8217;s break things.
```

...Which results in reddit double encoding the ampersand:

```
apostrophe&amp;#8217;s break things.
```

I've tried the functions the_title_attribute(), the_title(), html_entity_decode(), and htmlspecialchars_decode() all to no avail - certain encodings remain.

Anyone know a way around this? Like a way to get the raw unencoded title from the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$title = get_post_field('post_title', $post_id, 'raw');
```

However I'd get to the bottom of what encoding reddit code would prefer. Echoing raw stuff is poor idea for security.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly. Thanks.

Can you elaborate on how echoing raw stuff is a poor idea for security?

Comment: @Jartron it is general security concept that any output should be properly cleaned in a way appropriate to output context. See [Data Validation > Output Sanitation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Output_Sanitation) in Codex.